Нужна запятая при адресе?
Нужна запятая?

Здравствуйте, Александра. Вы бы согласились приезжать на адрес ЖК «Ручьи», Северный проспект 123, к. 1(,) — к ребёнку 3-го класса на 1,5 часа за 1100 руб.?


"Ребенок 3-го класса на полтора часа" - очередной шедевр, спасибо, сделал моё утро.

Здравствуйте, Александра. Вы согласны ездить к ребёнку третьекласснику за 1100 руб. за 1,5 часа, по адресу Северный проспект 123, к. 1 - ЖК «Ручьи»?

Лучше - без ребенка)  У наших соседей ребенок 6-го класса  ростом 1.75 м

@Sharon да, лучше без ребёнка(мне тоже), а то ещё к ребенку-третьекласснику, видимо. Ох) сколько подробностей и уместить нужно в одно предложение

Сообщение вообще сомнительное: согласитесь приезжать за 1100 рублей. Стиль текста  должен быть деловым. Вы могли бы приезжать по следующему адресу...  школьник 3-го класса, 1100 руб за 1.5 часа.
